# Prestashop Updating Custom Product Field

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have problems with updating a Product (custom fields) in Prestashop.

I followed the tutorial: http://blog.belvg.com/how-to-create-a-custom-product-tab-in-prestashop.html

It works quite fine, when I save a product the normal way. But Prestashop 1.6 has an autosave function, when changing stock or prices. This makes my custom fields empty. By trial & error I found out, that my hookActionProductUpdate function causes the problem, but I dont know why:

```
public function hookActionProductUpdate($params) {
    $id_product = Tools::getValue('id_product');
    $sampleObj = Belvg_Sample::loadByIdProduct($id_product);
    $sampleObj->lagerplatz = Tools::getValue('lagerplatz');
    $sampleObj->artnrlfr = Tools::getValue('artnrlfr');
    $sampleObj->archiv = Tools::getValue('archiv');
    $sampleObj->bundle = Tools::getValue('bundle');
    $sampleObj->beschrieb = Tools::getValue('beschrieb');
    $sampleObj->oldartnr = Tools::getValue('oldartnr');

    $sampleObj->id_product = $id_product;

    if(!empty($sampleObj) && isset($sampleObj->id)){
        $sampleObj->update();
    } else {
        $sampleObj->add();
    }
}
```

What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually add an hidden field in the form

```
<input type="hidden" name="CUSTOM_TAB_LOADED" value="1">
```

Then in the update function

```
if(!Tools::getValue('CUSTOM_TAB_LOADED'))
     return;
```

this way you only save it if it was loaded.